# Automatically copy text when clicked on input area (multiple lnputs) Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get input area to copy text when the user clicks on it. The code itself is selecting correct text but when i add copy function it won't copy correct text. Problem is that this is a template which website use to add elements to the website (so multiple submissions will use same code).

```
echo '<div class="input-group input-group-sm">';
echo '<span class="input-group-addon input-label-' . strtolower($server->status_text) . '"><i class="fa fa-server" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;' . $server->status_text . '</span>';
echo '<input type="text" onclick="this.select()" value="' . $server->address . (($server->connection_port != '25565') ? ":" . $server->connection_port : null) . '">';echo '</div>';
```

Output on site:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
<span class="input-group-addon input-label-online"><i class="fa fa-server" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Online</span>
<input type="text" onclick="this.select()" class="form-control" value="Server IP">
</div>
```

Edit: It looks like i will need to do this via button as using "onclick" is crashing my website. Not sure how to do it with button and without some sort of ID system. The servers are listed via "table" if that helps.

Comment: I don't think that will work to copy text from an input box. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? What are you planning to do with the copied text?  At first glance, this seems like a job that jQuery can handle.

Comment: I don't think there is any need for jQuery - execCommand("Copy") is very straight forward. I think you just have a problem with elements that you are referencing. Can you show code example with multiple elements as you are describing?

Comment: The copied text is not for website but for user, so they don't need to use right click and copy (in the section IP of the server will display). So overall this is only basic Input group with addon. Website is using same code for all servers added to website and it's getting information of server by "$server->status_text". (I have added output to first post.)

Comment: I would love to know how a purely client-side copy/paste to clipboard crashes your entire website if you use onclick....

Comment: I checked 5 times if i made any error on it and it all looked good. As i saved it without code (as it was) it works fine but as soon as i add code it gave me error 500. Not sure why tho. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<input type="text" onclick="this.select(); document.execCommand('Copy');" class="form-control" value="Server IP">
```

The code you were trying has unescaped parentheses.

This works with multiple input elements: https://jsfiddle.net/xx0gs6Lw/

EDIT

That must be only syntax error then, can you post your exact code? It should look something like this:

```
echo '<input type="text" onclick="this.select(); document.execCommand(\'Copy\');" value="' . $server->address . (($server->connection_port != '25565') ? ":" . $server->connection_port : null) . '">';
```

Comment: I just notice the same problem i got yesterday. For some reason website is giving me Error 500 when i add this code to it. But if i add it directly to the website (by editing source in Chrome it will work). Maybe if i do it via button it might work but again couldn't get that code up as all of them are using ID.

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing your code, but Error 500 looks like syntax error...